# Dividing rows in same column based on another column value

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm new to python and working with dataframes. I have a dataframe formated as below.

```
TYPE | FLAG | PROP
---- | ---- | ----
A    | 0    | 0.1
B    | 0    | 0.2
C    | 0    | 0.5
D    | 0    | 0.2
A    | 1    | 0.15
B    | 1    | 0.4
C    | 1    | 0.3
D    | 1    | 0.15
```

I want to create a new data frame of indexes for TYPE. (i.e. divide PROP for FLAG = 1 by PROP for FLAG = 0)

Ideally I want to end up with (i've left the calculation in if that helps):

```
TYPE | INDEX 
---- | ---- 
A    | 1.5  (= 0.15/0.1)   
B    | 2    (=0.4/0.2)
C    | 0.6  (=0.3/0.5)    
D    | 0.75 (=0.15/0.2)
```

If I were to use SQL I would probably write something like this.

```
select type, 
one_prop/zero_prop as index 
from (
select account_type 
, max(case when index=1 then prop else 0 end) as prop_A
, max(case when index=0 then prop else 0 end) as prop_B
from table
) a
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have a feeling `df.groupby()` is going to help me here, although I'm not entirely sure how.

Please note this is a simplified version of my problem, I don't think it should affect the solution too much but there are other columns which I am not interested in and don't factor into the calculation.

Comment: Are rows by TYPE with FLAG duplicated?

Comment: No they are not. There is only one combination of each value of TYPE & FLAG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape and then divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['TYPE','FLAG'])['PROP'].unstack()
df['INDEX'] = df[1].div(df[0])
#drop columns, reset index and remove column name
df = df.drop([0,1], axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  TYPE  INDEX
0    A   1.50
1    B   2.00
2    C   0.60
3    D   0.75
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df = df.pivot(index='TYPE', columns='FLAG', values='PROP')
df['INDEX'] = df[1].div(df[0])
df = df.drop([0,1], axis=1).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
  TYPE  INDEX
0    A   1.50
1    B   2.00
2    C   0.60
3    D   0.75
```

Solution with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = df.pivot(index='TYPE', columns='FLAG', values='PROP')
a = df[1].div(df[0])
df = pd.DataFrame({'TYPE':a.index,'INDEX':a.values}, columns=['TYPE','INDEX'])
print (df)
  TYPE  INDEX
0    A   1.50
1    B   2.00
2    C   0.60
3    D   0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

As you basically have two equal-size and equal-indexed dataframes into one, you can just split them back in two views against `FLAG` and do the math:

```
df.set_index('TYPE', inplace=True)

df
Out[17]: 
      FLAG  PROP
TYPE            
A        0  0.10
B        0  0.20
C        0  0.50
D        0  0.20
A        1  0.15
B        1  0.40
C        1  0.30
D        1  0.15

df[df.FLAG==1]['PROP']/df[df.FLAG==0]['PROP']
Out[18]: 
TYPE
A    1.50
B    2.00
C    0.60
D    0.75
Name: PROP, dtype: float64
```